# how to use grep without change the output order

Tags: grep

I have two files (LIST.txt and FILE1.txt). I'm trying to use the script grep to obtain an output in the same order of LIST.txt

**LIST.txt**

```
rs201196551
rs8071824
rs74620303
```

**FILE1.txt**

```
rs201196551 red
rs74620303 blue
rs9000000 pink
rs8071824 purple
```

I used this code: `grep -wFf LIST.txt FILE1.txt > OUTPUT.txt`

And I obtained this output:

```
rs201196551 red
rs74620303 blue
rs8071824 purple
```

But actually I expect this output:

```
rs201196551 red
rs8071824 purple
rs74620303 blue
```

(in the same order of LIST.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the output order of `grep` without additional tools. However, here is an awk that buffers the output in the order of the list file:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                                            # process list file
    a[$0]=++c                                        # store first word in a hash
    next                                             # process next list item
}
{                                                    # process file1
    for(i in a)                                      # for each list item
        if($1==i) {                                  # see if it is the first word
            b[a[i]]=b[a[i]] (b[a[i]]==""?"":ORS) $0  # store to output buffer
            next                                     # no more candidates after match
        }
}
END {                                                # in the end
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++)                                # start outputing
        if(b[i]!="")                                 # skip empties
            print b[i]               
}' list file1
```

Output:

```
rs201196551 red
rs8071824 purple
rs74620303 blue
```

**Update**: From the comments, thanks @Sundeep:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {         # lets hash the haystack instead ie. file1
    a[$1]=$0
    next
} 
($0 in a) {       # now read the needles from the list and lookup from a
    print a[$0]
}' file1 list
```

Output:

```
rs201196551 red
rs8071824 purple
rs74620303 blue
```

However, if there are identical entries (of `$1`) in the `file1`, they will be lost (due to `a[$1]=$0`). Last entry in the file will remain.

Comment: why not reverse the input file list and use `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} ($0 in a){print a[$0]}'` ?

Comment: @Sundeep Yeah, that would do it, too. Usually the haystack is bigger than the needle so I wanted to hash the needles instead (creating similar condition with output buffering, though :).